# change display_rotate at runtime (for kodi)

Tags: raspbian, display, kodi

Is there a way to modify the "display_rotate" setting in "config.txt" at runtime?

Mainly I want to flip the display horizontally occasionally while running kodi.

I'm using a RPi 2 B on Raspbian 3.18.11-v7+

Comment: Have your tried using xrandr? I believe if you use this within a script you may have to provide a display i.e. `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output 'default' --rotate right` . It's been a while since I've used xrandr but you might have better luck looking at the man pages. As far as I know changing display_rotate in the `/boot/config.txt` file won't change anything until rebooted. If I am mistaken you can create some patch files and use them to rotate the display.

Comment: @BrettReinhard As far as I know Kodi can't run inside an X11 system on RPi, it can only run standalone using framebuffer and OpenGLES directly. So xrandr won't work.

Answer (score 1):

On boot press the Shift key. Select the os you wish to edit. Press on the edit Button. This will allow you to modify the setting to the display_rotate and lcd_rotate.

Had a problem with display_rotate=2, did not work. So after hacking around with it and looking at how the registers were set I used display_rotate=4. Worked correctly.

Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work while kodi is running already.